# Call requires permission which may be rejected by the user when trying to get the location

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation

I looked on other questions, but was unable to find the anwer.
Anyway, I am trying to get the location of the device, and it just wont work. I am using Android 5.0 (API 21).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

The error is when in .getLastKnowLocation(). It says I should check for permissions, but I already added the permissions to the Android manifest.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

When I click the red light bulb, there is 'Add permission check' option, and when I click it, it ads this:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
```

But when I run it, it always does the return; , like I don't have the permissions.

Comment: Check Android runtime permissions

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable run time permissions,

```
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1200);
```

Comment: try calling this if the permission was not granted in on-create. though run time permissions really began in Android 6.0 (API level 23)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want your app to work up to API level 21, you can set `targetSdkVersion 21` in your module level `build.gradle` file, which will make the error you're facing go away.

If/when you want to start targeting API level 23 or higher, you'll need to request permissions at runtime in addition to having them declared in your manifest.